# if... !true conditional rendering in nunjucks

Tags: templates, nunjucks

`if...true` conditionals work like a charm as [outlined here](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#if) in the docs.

but if I try to do something like:

```
{% if !posts.length %}
<i>No project posts yet!</i>
{% endif %}
```

I get an error:

```
Template render error: (/home/nak/clones/mf3/views/project.html) [Line 10, Column 9]
 unexpected token: !
```

I've worked around this by doing:

```
{% if posts.length %}
{% else %}
<i>No project posts yet!</i>
{% endif %}
```

Is there a better (correct) way to do this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I see you've got a bit of a bobby dazzler here.

Try using `not` instead of `!`.

In other words, use `not`, not `!`!

Give 'er a go mate and notice that in the raw section here they highlight `not` as if it's a keyword.

https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#raw

Best of luck to ye.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the syntax:

```
<% '' if posts.length else 'No project posts yet!' %>
```

https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#if-expression